# What is the functionality of "android.intent.category.MONKEY"?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have searched about it, But unable to find any good documentation on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `android.intent.category.MONKEY` to activity means that

> This activity may be exercised by the monkey or other automated test
>   tools.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_MONKEY)

[How to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939402/android-using-categories-in-monkey)

Answer (score 8):

The Monkey is a program that runs on your emulator or device and generates pseudo-random streams of user events such as clicks, touches, or gestures, as well as a number of system-level events. You can use the Monkey to stress-test applications that you are developing, in a random yet repeatable manner. check [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html).
The simplest way to use the monkey is with the following command, which launches your application and sends `500 pseudo-random` events to it.

```
adb shell monkey -v -p your.package.name 500
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that the activity should be launched by the automated testing tool Monkey.